# System beeps on shutdown

Tags: 10.04, sound

Very recently a couple of our systems have started making beeps on shutdown, we've not been able to isolate the exact time that they've been updated and it's occuring, but I've narrowed it down to being not pcspkr or snd_pcsp as both are blacklisted under modprobe, and rmmod'ed just to be sure. Now I'm a bit puzzled as I was under the impression those were the only two modules that could make the beep, is there a third lurking that I need to blacklist?

Edit:
I've copied the results of lsmod over [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1Tj7YgWX).

Comment: Ubuntu overriding the default behaviour of a sound module is reasonably common (there's even a Launchpad bug for it).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I never actually found the root cause but I can describe the workaround I've put in place.

Comment: +1 excellent - if you are content - click the tick button next to your answer to close.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer why we get the problem but to fix it I ended up writing a Python script that uses amixer and alsactl to programatically tell ALSA to reduce volume to 0% and set mute for 'PC Beep', 'Beep' and 'PC Speaker'. It's not bullet proof, as I've found machines with PC speakers that have slightly different names, but it resolved the bulk of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be unrelated to linux: FreeBSD and Windows users report this too; also some graphics cards come with beepers these days, so it may be an age / heat related issue. I'd recommend opening the affected PCs and cleaning their interiors from dust.

Comment: It's doesn't persist with fresh installs, in fact I struggle to duplicate it. I've narrowed it down to being Intel HDA PC Beep (I think) and I can mute it with alsamixer (sort of but not fully), so I don't think it's a hardware one in this case.